# Convert groupyby attributes into specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe which I have created out of a `groupby` operation (see code and output below):

```
Index=right_asset_df.groupby(['Year','Asset_Type']).agg({'Titre':'count','psqm':'median','Superficie':'median', 'Montant':'median'}).reset_index()
```

The output is:

[image]

Instead of having `Asset_Type` as rows, I would like to have it as columns which means that the new output `Index` should have one column for each `Asset_Type` (Appart and Villa).

Here is an example of the output:

[image]

As you can see, the groupby attributes `Asset_Type` as one specific column each.

How can I do that in python please? Thanks

Comment: Please add the expected output to the question.

Comment: Added the output. Thank you for asking for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way is to use Pivot:

```
# Pivot table with (index, columns, values)
df = Index.pivot(['Year'], 'Asset_Type',['Titre','psqm','Superficie','Montant']).reset_index()

# Instack multi level in columns
df.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df.columns]
```